# Toggle between Images asp.net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, image, razor, src, user-profile

I have a place holder for a profile photo.I want it to get profile image from database (this works OK)`<img src="@Url.Action("Thumbnail", "Photo", new { id = Model.Mebrief.myGuid, size = "small" })"  alt="@Model.UserName" width="150" height="150"/>`.
Problem:
If there is no profile image ,it should get default place holder image located here:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/profile-template/img/friend_avatar_default.jpg")" alt="crazy" width="150" height="150"/>
```

All these are supposed to show in a div below:

```
<div id="profile">   </div>
```

NOTE: I am using **.cshtml razer** page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this in your controller.

```
 public ActionResult Photo(int photoId)
    {
        MyPhoto photo = null;
        try
        {
            MyPhoto = db.GetMyPhotoById(photoId);
            return new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(photo.Image), photo.ImageMimeType);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //use the default image
            return new FilePathResult(Url.Content("~/Content/profile-template/img/friend_avatar_default.jpg"), "image/jpg");
        }
    }
```

It would be helpful to see what you are doing in your controller, but I'm guessing you are returning a FileStreamResult from the bytes you get back from the database.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> below is not a valid razor syntax but just an idea -  Use ternary operator

```
if true ? new image : default image
```

Model != null

**?**
img src="@Url.Action("Thumbnail", "Photo", new { id = Model.Mebrief.myGuid, size = "small" })" alt="@Model.UserName" width="150" height="150"/>"

**:**

img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/profile-template/img/friend_avatar_default.jpg")" alt="crazy" width="150" height="150"/>